# Returning results with distinct id from 1 field, largest id from a 2nd field, and filtered on a specific value from a 3rd field

Tags: sql-server

I've been trying to build a query to report on executions of test cases. Here's a very simplified data set I'll use as an example:

`TestCase id  Test Case Name                   Execution id  Attribute    Result
 1            Log in to machine                1                Windows 7    Pass
 1           Log in to machine                2             Windows 8    Fail
 1           Log in to machine                3             Windows 10   Pass
 2           Log out of machine               4             Windows 7    Pass
 3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine 5             Windows 7    Pass
 2           Log out of machine               6             Windows 8    Pass
 3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine 7             Windows 8    Pass
 2           Log out of machine               8             Windows 10   Pass
 3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine 9             Windows 10   Pass
 3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine 10            Windows 8    Pass
 1           Log in to machine                11            Windows 8    Fail
 2           Log out of machine               12            Windows 8    Pass`

What I would like to be able to do is return something in the fashion of this (I know this isn't valid SQL but is more like pseudo SQL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
WHERE Attribute=<some attribute to report on> AND Max(Execution id)
ORDER BY Test Case id
```

Whenever I have tried this, I run into 2 issues.

- The first one is returning only distinct test case ids. The closest I've come to doing this uses group by but then it requires me to include the result in the group by clause which gives me the last passing result and last failing result (I don't want both... just the last result).
- The other issue I run into is trying to use the Max(Execution id). I'm not an expert on SQL and have tried differing methods to do this with little success.

I've tried including it in the `where` clause, in a `having` clause, and using sub queries. I've read some about partition by clauses but I'm not that familiar with them and haven't gotten that to work either.

Here are the pseudo SQL statements with what I would like to see returned from the above data set but without the execution id. I don't care if the execution id is returned or not, I'm only including it to distinguish the rows for this question (the data set I'm working with is a lot more complex so hopefully I didn't miss any constraints):

```
Select distinct(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
Where Attribute=Windows 7 AND Max(Execution id)
Order By Test Case id
```

`TestCase id    Test Case Name                    Attribute   Result    Execution id
1           Log in to machine                 Windows 7   Pass      1
2           Log out of machine                Windows 7   Pass      4
3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine  Windows 7   Pass      5`

```
Select distinct(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
Where Attribute=Windows 8 AND Max(Execution id)
Order By Test Case id
```

`TestCase id    Test Case Name                    Attribute   Result    Execution id
1           Log in to machine                 Windows 8   Fail      11
2           Log out of machine                Windows 8   Pass      12
3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine  Windows 8   Pass      10`

```
Select distinct(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
Where Attribute=Windows 10 AND Max(Execution id)
Order By Test Case id
```

`TestCase id   Test Case Name                    Attribute   Result    Execution id
1           Log in to machine                 Windows 10  Pass      3
2           Log out of machine                Windows 10  Pass      8
3           Do crazy hacker stuff on machine  Windows 10  Pass      9`

Any ideas on other things I could try? Am I missing something simple here? Or is this just not possible to do?

I was wondering if I could use the results where I got both the last pass and last fail and use some logic on it to compare which has a larger exec id and only show that one but I'm not sure if you can even do that kind of stuff using only SQL.

I'm not looking for something with super performance, just something that works since it will only be used for reporting and doesn't need to run often.

Comment: I think the `ROW_NUMBER` function is what you're looking for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I needed... obviously just a gap in my knowledge of sql but searching around didn't lead me to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Row_Number like @podiluska suggests.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT  *, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [TestCase id], [Attribute] ORDER BY [Execution id] DESC) Rn 
    FROM    Table1
    -- WHERE Attribute = can go here
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE Rn = 1 -- Top result ordered by [Execution id] Desc
```

Comment: Yea, this works perfectly. I've added a Row_Number to the query I've been using and I'm getting the results I wanted. Better yet I feel I can manipulate this to show what I want a lot easier than before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This feels like some kind of SQL test.  This is what I came up with in 'interpreting your pseudo sql code':

Question 1:

```
Select distinct(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
Where Attribute=Windows 7 AND Max(Execution id)
Order By Test Case id
```

Answer 1:

```
SELECT [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result, Max([Execution id]) AS [Max Execution id]
FROM TableName
WHERE Attribute = 'Windows 7'
GROUP BY [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result
```

Answer 2:
(same as question 1, only different WHERE clause):

```
SELECT [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result, Max([Execution id]) AS [Max Execution id]
FROM TableName
WHERE Attribute = 'Windows 8'
GROUP BY [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result
ORDER BY [Test Case id]
```

Question 3:
Select distinct(Test Case id), Test Case Name, Attribute, Result
Where Attribute=Windows 10 AND Max(Execution id)
Order By Test Case id

Answer 3:
(same as question 2, only different WHERE clause):

```
SELECT [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result, Max([Execution id]) AS [Max Execution id]
FROM TableName
WHERE Attribute = 'Windows 10'
GROUP BY [Test Case id], [Test Case Name], Attribute, Result
ORDER BY [Test Case id]
```

> I was wondering if I could use the results where I got both the last
>   pass and last fail and use some logic on it to compare which has a
>   larger exec id and only show that one but I'm not sure if you can even
>   do that kind of stuff using only SQL.

- you can certainly do that kind of thing in a single query (with subqueries), or a series of queries.  You just need to nest them or order them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the LAST_VALUE function with OVER clause.

Create and populate table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TestCase
(
    ExecutionId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TestCaseId int NOT NULL,
    TestCaseName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Attribute nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Result nvarchar(4) NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TestCase (TestCaseId, TestCaseName, ExecutionId, Attribute, Result)
    VALUES
    (1, N'Log in to machine', 1 , N'Windows 7', N'Pass'),
    (1, N'Log in to machine', 2 , N'Windows 8', N'Fail'),
    (1, N'Log in to machine', 3 , N'Windows 10', N'Pass'),
    (2, N'Log out of machine', 4 , N'Windows 7', N'Pass'),
    (3, N'Do crazy hacker stuff on machine', 5, N'Windows 7', N'Pass'),
    (2, N'Log out of machine', 6 , N'Windows 8', N'Pass'),
    (3, N'Do crazy hacker stuff on machine', 7, N'Windows 8', N'Pass'),
    (2, N'Log out of machine', 8 , N'Windows 10', N'Pass'),
    (3, N'Do crazy hacker stuff on machine', 9, N'Windows 10', N'Pass'),
    (3, N'Do crazy hacker stuff on machine', 10, N'Windows 8', N'Pass'),
    (1, N'Log in to machine', 11, N'Windows 8', N'Fail'),
    (2, N'Log out of machine', 12, N'Windows 8', N'Pass');
```

Then the SELECT statement with CTE.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT TestCaseId, TestCaseName, Attribute, ExecutionId, LAST_VALUE(Result) OVER(PARTITION BY TestCaseId, TestCaseName, Attribute ORDER BY ExecutionID) AS 'LastResult'
        FROM dbo.TestCase
)
SELECT TestCaseId, TestCaseName, Attribute, LastResult
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY TestCaseId, TestCaseName, Attribute, LastResult
    ORDER BY TestCaseId, Attribute;
```

[image]